# What is best practice for confirming success of Update queries

Tags: update

If I am doing a SQL Update query that affects, for instance, 1000 rows, how do I check that the query worked as intended and didn't hit any strange edge cases, (short of examining each row visually myself)?
What is best practice for this ?

Additional info requested in comments
I was writing a SQL query to update any fields in a column that were blank with a standard value. That by itself is pretty easy and the number of fields were small enough that I could check them visually. But I figured there could be much more complex queries covering larger numbers of fields where examining wasn't feasible.

Comment: Can you give us some examples? Are you concerned about more rows or less being updated?  or the update syntax being messed up?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: For logical validation (optimistic locking) you would use the update count, for physical validation it is enough to not get an error on (auto)commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query before and after looking for the particular conditions you are wanting to update.

For adhoc queries it's a good idea to run the query as a select statement using the same where clause *before* running as an update statement.

The update should update exactly the same rows select returned unless the data has changed.

```
create table #test ([id] int identity (1,1), [status] varchar(50) )

insert into #test VALUES ('COMPLETED')
insert into #test VALUES ('FAULTED')
insert into #test VALUES ('COMPLETED')
insert into #test VALUES ('FAULTED')
insert into #test VALUES ('FAULTED')    

select status
from #test 
where status = 'FAULTED'

select count(*) 
from #test 
where status = 'FAULTED'

update #test 
set status = 'FAILED'
where status = 'FAULTED'

select count(*) 
from #test 
where status = 'FAULTED'

select status, count(*) 
from #test 
group by status
```

Answer (score 1):

Script belong to `Sql Server`. but my above idea is for any DBMS.

Main goal should be `fullfilling requirement, error free Script and best performance.`

Why would I want to know everytime that whether those 1000 rows were updated sucessfully or not ? why would i want to know about each rows ?

when my script is properly tested and it has pass through QA phase.

Why i will write unnecessary code to verify when it is not actual biz. requirement ?

If it is not actually biz. requirement then I write update Sql within Try-Catch and return simple output int para,indicating pass/fail.

Also log the exception in catch.review your log table.

in case you really need to know the updated output then OUTPUT Clause is very handy in sql server.

```
create table #t (id int identity(1,1),col int)
insert into #t values(1),(2)
declare @Outputtbl table (col int);

update #t
set col=3
output inserted.col into @Outputtbl

select * from @Outputtbl

--select * from #t

drop table #t
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  At my current employer, there is not a formal testing or QA phase, (and there would be no one to do it), The suggestion of the OUTPUT clause could be useful though.